# Evolución del significado de "cronómetro"

Tags: significado, historia, sustantivos, acepciones

[**Cronómetro**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BMCbDEc) aparece definido en el actual DLE como

> De *crono*- y *‒́metro*.
>   1. m. Reloj de gran precisión para medir fracciones de tiempo muy pequeñas, utilizado en industria y en competiciones deportivas.

Sin embargo, la primera vez que aparece en el DRAE es en [**1832**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.0.0.0.0.), con un significado completamente diferente:

> CRONÓMETRO. m. Reloj de longitudes.

¿Qué es un "reloj de longitudes"? ¿Cómo se ha pasado de una definición a otra tan diferente?

Comment: El término 'cronómetro' puede significar un [cronómetro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronómetro) o un [cronómetro *marino*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronómetro_marino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Técnicamente, el significado de *cronómetro* no ha variado a lo largo de la historia. En la práctica, su significado se ha fusionado con el de *cronógrafo*.

El hecho de que en un principio el significado de *cronómetro* sea el que indicas se deriva del hecho de que los cronómetros eran máquinas caras y complejas que se usaban en los barcos para resolver [el problema de determinar su longitud](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron%C3%B3metro_marino):

> Para determinar una posición sobre la superficie de la Tierra, es necesario y suficiente conocer su latitud, su longitud y su altitud, dándose la circunstancia en el caso de los barcos de que las determinaciones altimétricas no tienen ninguna relevancia, porque operan a nivel del mar. Hasta mediados de la década de 1750, la navegación precisa en mar abierto sin tierra a la vista era un problema sin resolver, debido a la dificultad de calcular la longitud. Los navegantes pueden determinar su latitud fácilmente midiendo el ángulo del sol sobre el horizonte al mediodía (es decir, cuando llega a su punto más alto en el cielo, o culminación). Sin embargo, para encontrar su longitud, es imprescindible disponer de un dispositivo que permita conocer con precisión un tiempo estándar de referencia a bordo del barco.

Para este menester, durante el siglo XVIII y más en el XIX se popularizó el uso de cronómetros en los barcos, que se sincronizaban con la hora medida en un meridiano de referencia (como el de Greenwich). Por tanto, estos aparatos únicamente medían la hora actual, el hecho de que esa medición de la hora actual sirviera para calcular la longitud es circunstancial.

Hoy día un cronómetro sigue sirviendo para lo mismo: medir la hora con gran precisión. Lo que pasa es que la gente usa los términos *cronómetro* y *cronógrafo* indistintamente. La tercera acepción del DLE para *[cronógrafo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=BM00C1c)* es la siguiente:

> 3. m. Reloj o aparato que sirve para medir con exactitud tiempos sumamente pequeños.

Y según [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron%C3%B3metro):

> Un cronógrafo es un reloj que, mediante algún mecanismo de complicación, permite la medición independiente de tiempos. Normalmente, en su versión analógica van provistos de un pulsador de puesta en marcha y paro así como otro segundo pulsador de puesta a cero.

Así pues, los cronómetros miden con precisión el tiempo absoluto, y los cronógrafos miden con precisión el tiempo en un intervalo. En la práctica, para mí un cronómetro sirve para 
medir el tiempo en un intevalo, y lo otro es un reloj.